# How to use Include method in LINQ To Entity when not sure that it has the specified navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I give you a CF example:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> A { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public int E { set; get; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public int F { set; get; }
}

public class C : A
{
    public int G { set; get; }
    public virtual D D { set; get; }
}

public class D { }
```

and the query is like this:

```
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
       var queryResult = context.A.Include("D").Select(a => a);
    }
```

and it throws an exception with this message:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'A' does not
>   declare a navigation property with the name 'D'.

How would you solve this **with only one LINQ To Entity query**?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around

```
using (var context = new MyContext())

{
   var typeA=typeOf(A);
   var queryResult ;      
   if( typeA.GetProperty("D")!=null)
         queryResult  = context.A.Include("D").Select(a => a);


}
```

Comment: It will never give any result, because the type 'A' doesn't have the property 'D' and the if condition will always be false. And even if it would work, I want the result of the query to contain all the entities of type 'A' and all of the derived types (B and C) that exist.

Comment: `I want the result of the query to contain all the entities of type 'A' and all of the derived types (B and C)`Seems like  u are expecting to load A with there derived types. `DbSet<A> A` returns object types of A always. You won't get any B,C there . But you will get all the objects of A. Some of them are related to B and C. But you can't get B or C from A directly.

Comment: context.A.Where(a => a is B) does exactly that but I want to have all the navigation properties automatically